# PrimeFaces DataTable: (Multi)selection does not work for dynamically built tables giving only nulls

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working with the multiple row selection to give a user ability to delete the selecting records. According to the PDF documentation, and the ShowCase Labs, I must use the code translated to the Java like that:

```java
final DataTable = new DataTable();
...
// (1)
dataTable.setSelectionMode("multiple");
// (2)
dataTable.setValueExpression("selection", createValueExpression(DbeBean.class, "selection", Object[].class));
// (3)
dataTable.setValueExpression("rowKey", createValueExpression("#{" + VARIABLE + ".indexKey}", Object.class));
...
final ClientBehaviorHolder dataTableAsHolder = dataTable;
...
// (4)
dataTableAsHolder.addClientBehavior("rowSelect", createAjaxBehavior(createMethodExpression(metaData.controllerBeanType, "onRowSelect", void.class, new Class<?>[] {SelectEvent.class})));
```

1. multiple - This line features the multiple selection, works fine visually at the front-end.
2. selection - Being invoked, the #{dbeBean.selection} is really bound and the `public void setSelection(T[] selection)` is only invoked.
3. rowKey - Being invoked, works fine, the `getIndexKey()` is invoked and returns the necessary result.
4. rowSelect - This event handler is invoked too, `DbeBean.onRowSelect(SelectEvent e)`.

I also use lazy data model (I don't really believe it may be the reason but who knows?; by the way, it returns `List<T>` though setSelection() requires `T[]` -- why it's like that?):

```java
public abstract class AbstractLazyDataSource<T extends IIndexable<K>, K> extends LazyDataModel<T> { 
... 
@Override
public final List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
    ...
    final IResultContainer<T> resultContainer = getData(querySpecifier);
    final List<T> data = resultContainer.getData();
    setRowCount(resultContainer.getTotalEntitiesCount());
    return getPage(data, first, pageSize);
}   
... 
@Override
public final K getRowKey(T object) {
    return object.getIndexKey(); // T instanceof IIndexable<K>, have to return a unique ID
}
...
```

However, the handlers do not work as they are expected to work. Please help me to understand why (2) `DbeBean.setSelection(T[] selection)` & (4) `DbeBean.onRowSelect(SelectEvent e)` get only the **null** value: `T[] selection = null`, and `SelectEvent: e.getObject = null`, respectively. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

- PrimeFaces 3.2
- Mojarra 2.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it to work: I simply removed the `rowKey` property during to the dynamic `p:dataTable` creation (DataTable), and simply overloaded `getRowData` in lazy data model. Now it works.